# Palindrome Numbers

Tags: java

I am writing Java code in which I have to create a method that returns boolean with one parameter. The code has to identify in true or false if the number (parameter) provided to it is palindrome or not. This is my code but the outcome is false all the time. Can someone identify what is wrong here?

```
public class NumberPalindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPalindrome(121));

    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
        int reverse = 0;
        boolean variable = true;
        while (number > 0) {
            int lastdigit = number % 10;
            reverse *= 10;
            reverse += lastdigit;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        if (reverse==number) {
            variable = true;
        } else variable = false;
        return variable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. You may want to familiarize yourself with the debugging features of your favorite IDE. Or at least print out `reverse` and `number` when you are comparing it

Comment: At the end of your `while` loop, you've reduced `number` to zero, then you're trying to compare it to `reverse`.

Comment: When i use the below code, it works:

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 525;
        int mynumber = isPalindrome(number);
        System.out.println(mynumber);
        if (mynumber == number) {
            System.out.println("True");
        } else System.out.println("False");

Comment: }
    public static int isPalindrome(int number) {
        int reverse = 0;
        while (number > 0) {
            int lastdigit = number % 10;
            reverse *= 10;
            reverse += lastdigit;
            number = number / 10;
        }
       return reverse;
    }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and computer programming. As you continue to learn Java, you need to also learn how to debug. It is easy to make mistakes in your code. Even as a professional programmer, I rarely get it right the first time. To start, I suggest [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) that has a few tips to get you started.

Comment: On a side note, I strongly suggest using descriptive variable names. For example, `variable` isn't very descriptive. Instead you can do something like `result`.

Answer (score 4):

You must keep in memory the initial value of `number` given in parameter to be able to compare it later with `reverse`. The code will look like this.

```
public class NumberPalindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPalindrome(121));

    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
        int initialNumber = number;
        int reverse = 0;
        boolean variable = true;
        while (number > 0) {
            int lastdigit = number % 10;
            reverse *= 10;
            reverse += lastdigit;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        if (reverse==initialNumber) {
            variable = true;
        } else variable = false;
        return variable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you don't need the final `if`. You might just as well do `return reverse==initialNumber` and get rid of the `variable` variable.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is superb. I totally understand now. Thanks alot